# Images are loading in all pages except for one in Django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

So I am extending `base.html` onto another page in Django. The images load in every single page that extends the `base.html` except for one. I've included the `{% load static %}` tag inside the template that is not loading the image. I have no clue why the images are not loading in this one specific page. What's wrong with it?

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/style.css' %}" />
    <title>BugTracker</title>
    {% block htmlhead %}
    {% endblock htmlhead %}
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    
    <!-- END OF NAVBAR  -->
    <div class="container">
      {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
        <!-- END OF ASIDE -->
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/charts.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is where I am loading the `<img src>`

navbar.html

```
<nav>
  <div class="container2">
      <img src="../static/images/logo-no-background.png" class="logo">
      <div class="search-bar">
          <span class="material-icons-sharp">search</span>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <div class="profile-area">
          <div class="theme-btn">
              <span class="material-icons-sharp active">light_mode</span>
              <span class="material-icons-sharp">dark_mode</span>
          </div>
          <div class="profile">
              <div class="profile-photo">
                  <img src="../static/images/avatar.svg" alt="">
              </div>
              <h5>Miko Dawili</h5>
              <span class="material-icons-sharp">expand_more</span>
          </div>
          <button id="menu-btn">
              <span class="material-icons-sharp">menu</span>
          </button>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

sidebar.html

```
<!-- SIDEBAR -->

<aside>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="../static/images/logo-no-background.png" alt="">
            <h2>MA<span class="danger">BLE</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="close" id="close-btn">
            <span class="material-icons-sharp">close</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <a href="/">
            <span class="material-icons-sharp">grid_view</span>
            <h3>Dashboard</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="{% url 'manage-users' %}">
            <span class="material-icons-sharp">person_outline</span>
            <h3>Customers</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="{% url 'project-home' %}">
            <span class="material-icons-sharp">receipt_long</span>
            <h3>Projects</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="material-icons-sharp">insights</span>
            <h3>Analytics</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <span class="material-icons-sharp">mail_outline</span>
            <h3>Messages</h3>
            <span class="message-count">26</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="material-icons-sharp">settings</span>
            <h3>Settings</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="material-icons-sharp">logout</span>
            <h3>Logout</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
</aside>
<!-- SIDEBAR -->
```

template that's not loading the images

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  
<main id="content">
  <!-- <h1 class="title">Dashboard</h1> -->
  
  
</main>
{% endblock content %}
```

Another page that's similar that IS loading the images

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<main id="content">
  <h1 class="title"><a href="{% url 'create-project' %}" class="button-3" role="button">Create New Project</a></h1>
  <div class="recent-orders">
    <h2>Recent Orders</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Product Number</th>
                <th>Payment</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for project in page_obj %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="{% url 'project' project.id %}">{{project.name}}</a></td>
              <td>{{project.description}}</td>
                <td>Due</td>
                <td>{{project.created|date:"F d, Y"}}</td>
                <td class="primary">Details</td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <a href="#">Show All</a>
</div>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is what the non working page looks like

[image]

Here is what it should look like

[image]

Comment: From the broken image pictures on the screenshot, you can see the src attribute of the img tag is being set, but its not pointing to a file.  What is the src of those broken images and how is it different from the ones that work?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no difference. I have edited in the templates that have the `<img src>`  for you to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, what I did initially was use relative urls like so `<img src="../static/images/logo-no-background.png" alt="">` when I should have been using the static tag to load the images.

`<img src="{% static 'images/logo-no-background.png' %}" alt="">`

This works on all pages now.